# How are values actually fetched from an Enumerator object in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, enumerator

I'm interested in how values are fetched from an `Enumerator` object. In the following piece of code, I was expecting the first `enum.next` call to raise an exception as all values had already been received from `enum` after the call to `enum.to_a`.

```
enum = Enumerator.new do |yielder|
  yielder.yield 1
  yielder.yield 2
  yielder.yield 3
end

p enum.to_a # => [1, 2, 3]

puts enum.next # Expected StopIteration here
puts enum.next
puts enum.next
puts enum.next # => StopIteration exception raised
```

What's the difference between calling `next` vs an iterator method like `to_a` on an instance of `Enumerator`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: `to_a` always iterates over all elements and does not advance the position of the iterator. That is why [Enumerator#next](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) will start with the first element even if you have called `to_a` before. Calling `to_a` does not modify the enumerator object.

---

Here are the details:

#### Terms: internal vs external iteration

When discussing iterators in Ruby, two terms come up:

1. [internal iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator#Implicit_iterators) (also called implicit iteration)
2. [external iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator#External_iterators_and_the_iterator_pattern)

In your question, `enum.to_a` is an example for `enum` being used for internal iteration, while `enum.next` is an example of external iteration.

External iteration provides more control but is a more low-level operation. Internal iteration is often more elegant. The difference is that external iteration makes the state explicit (the current position), while the internal iteration implicitly applies to all elements.

#### Internal iteration: to_a

`to_a` will call [Enumerator#each](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-each), which iterates over the block **according to how this Enumerator was constructed**.

That is the critical point. As it does not operate on the internal state (the position) of the enumerator object from which it is called,
it does not interfere with the calls to `next` (the external iteration operation).

#### External iteration: next

When you create the Enumerator object, its state is initialized to point to the first object. You can modify the internal state by calling `next`, which will advance the position. Once all elements were consumed, it will raise a `StopIteration` exception.

Note that the state is only relevant when you are using the enumerator object for external iteration. That explains why you can safely call `to_a` on an enumerator that already consumed all elements, and it will still return a list of all elements. All internal iteration operations (e.g, `each`, `to_a,` map`) do not interfere with the external iteration.

#### Implementation in Rubinius

I looked at the [Rubinius](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius) source code to understand how it implemented there. Although it is not a language specification, it should be relatively close to the truth. Entry points:

- [Enumerable#to_a](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/enumerable.rb#L220) (arg will be empty)
- [Enumerator#next](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/enumerator.rb#L98)
- [Enumerator#each](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/enumerator.rb#L49)

Note that Enumerator includes [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html) as a mixin.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a copy of the enumerator"? Is a new copy created from something like `enum.dup` or `enum.clone`?

Comment: @AsadMoosvi I edited my answer. "Copying the enumerator" was indeed misleading. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Though peripheral to this question, I suggest you discuss the roll of the instance method `each` that is defined on every class that includes `Enumerable`. If, for example, we write `[1,2,3].map { |n| 2*n }`, we might ask how this works, considering that `map` is an `Enumerable` method, and all `Enumerable` methods have receivers that are enumerators, yet the array `[1,2,3]` is not an enumerator. As you know, when Ruby encounters this she inserts [Array#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-each) after the array to convert it to an enumerator: `[1,2,3].each.map { |n| 2*n }`.

Comment: I still don't get what you mean by "a copy of the enumerator in its original state."

Answer (score 1):

Calling `#next` moves the internal position forward, while `#to_a` doesn't consider the internal position at all. Try calling `next` once, then `to_a`, then `next` again to experiment.

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a